# Delayed evaluation for string formatting

Tags: javascript, string, formatting

I am building up a `constants.js` file with URLs used in my ReactJS project. These strings include query parameters that can be used with the URL. However, the values used in these strings are only available in a component where the string is used, not in the constants file itself. So for example, I want something like this:

```
export const BASE_URL = 'https://example.com';
export const FOO_QUERY = '?foo=%s';
```

where `%s` is just a placeholder that can be replaced later in a component. (I borrowed `printf()` syntax from C here for illustration purposes.) What is the correct syntax to do something like this in JavaScript? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably use a template literal in a function: The component calls the function with the `foo` value:

```
export const fooQuery = foo => `?foo=${foo}`;
```

Usage:

```
const query = fooQuery("foo value");
```

Answer (score 1):

With tagged template literals you could do:

```
 function query(parts, ...pos) {
   return apply(...args) {
     return parts.map((part, i) => part + args[ pos[i] ]).join("");
   }
}
```

Usable as:

```
 const find = query`?name=${0}&fullname=${0}&age=${1}`;

 console.log(find("jonas", 18));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let string = 'bar';
console.log("Foo %s", string);
var teststr = (string) => `Foo ${string}`; //result: Foo bar
```

Comment: I want to be able to use the formatted result as a string, either assign it to a variable or use it in a function call.

Comment: Then probably crowder's answer is useful.